# How to create directory dynamically if it doesn't exist in HDFS by using pyspark and set file and directory permission as well

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop
can we create directory in hadoop dyanamically?

currently I am using below command:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /data/test1/test2/test3/
```

and setting the file permission by using below command:

```
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /path /data/test1/test2/test3/t_bill_sheet.csv
```

By Dyanamically I mean {year} and iteratively inside it folder by date like 5,6,7 etc.

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a bash variable (or compute from current dates if you want) then reuse it over and over

```sh
YEAR=2000
MONTH=03
DAY=01
PATH="/data/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY"

hadoop fs -mkdir -p "$PATH"
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /path "$PATH/t_bill_sheet.csv"
```

Comment: though this is a well organised idea, but i need to integrate it with our product that is written in python, we don't want to use bash,

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using a combination of `exists()` and `mkdirs(`) method in pyspark as below

```
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

if not fs.exists(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("path")): #returns true or false
    fs.mkdirs(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("path"), FsPermission(777: Short) permission)
```